# Calling a function recursively with setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I want call few function one after another recursively with `setTimeout`.

```
var flag = 0 ;
function slave1(){
    if(flag < 60) {
        var COPY_PO_LINE_DIV = document.getElementById("DOM_ELEMENT1"); // Checking if DOM has loaded or not. If yes then doing something.
        if (COPY_PO_LINE_DIV != null) {
            flag = 0;
            //doing something
        } else { 
            setTimeout(slave1,2000); //waiting for 2 seconds and checking again.
        }
    }
}

//doing similar task
function slave2(){
    if(flag < 60) {
        var COPY_PO_LINE_DIV = document.getElementById("DOM_ELEMENT2");              
        if (COPY_PO_LINE_DIV != null) {
            flag = 0;
            //doing something
        } else {
            setTimeout(slave2,2000);
        }
    }
}

function master() {
    slave1();
    console.log("Without completing slave1 function.");
    slave2();
}
```

Through `master()` function I want to call multiple functions one after another, however in current situation its calling `slave2()` without completing `slave1()`. How can I make sure that `slave1()` has executed completed. If DOM element is not loaded than it should execute 60 times after every 2 seconds and than it should come out from `slave1()` and go to next one.

I want to execute same function for 60 times if dom element is not loaded without returning the control to next function.

Comment: Do you use any JS library or does it have to be pure JS?

Comment: Pure JS....................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to adjust `slave1` to run a callback when it is finished which will be `slave2`.

```
function slave1(callback){
    if(flag < 60) {
        var COPY_PO_LINE_DIV = document.getElementById("DOM_ELEMENT1"); // Checking if DOM has loaded or not. If yes then doing something.
        if (COPY_PO_LINE_DIV != null) {
            flag = 0;
            //doing something
            callback();
        } else { 
            setTimeout(slave1,2000); //waiting for 2 seconds and checking again.
        }
    }
}

function slave2(){...}

function master() {
    slave1(slave2);
    console.log("Without completing slave1 function.");
}
```

This is your basic javascript chaining. If you have more *slaves* you might want to look into [`async.series`](https://github.com/caolan/async) otherwise you go into callback hell as Gabs00 has put it nicely:

```
slave1(function(){
    slave2(function(){
        slave3(function(){
            slave4(slave5);
        });
    });
});
```

If you need to pass values to callbacks then you need to use an intermediate anonymous function which in turn calls the intended callback with the arguments in question. To do that, you need define your functions so that they use the arguments:

```
function slave1(str, callback){...}
function slave3(i, callback){...}

slave1("some argument", function(){
    slave2("another argument", function(){
        slave3(1, function(){
            slave4(2, slave5);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Helpfull... but suppose I have 5 functions in a row than how can I make a chain from them.

Comment: @Mike Then you effectively enter callback hell, consider promises

Comment: @Artjom-  If I have to pass few arguments as well?

Comment: @Mike Then you need to use an intermediate anonymous function which in turn calls the intended callback with the intended arguments. I added an arguments example

Answer (score 1):

Consider using promises for things like that. Here an implementation on top of jQuery, other promise libraries work similarly.

```
function waitForElement(elementId, maxTries, checkInterval) {
    var d = $.Deferred(), intvalID, checkFunc;

    // set up default values
    maxTries = maxTries || 60;
    checkInterval = checkInterval || 2000;

    checkFunc = function () {
        var elem = document.getElementById(elementId);
        if (maxTries-- > 0 && elem) {
            clearInterval(intvalID);
            d.resolve(elem);
        }
        if (maxTries <= 0) {
            clearInterval(intvalID);
            d.reject(elementId);
        }
    };

    // set up periodic check & do first check right-away
    intvalID = setInterval(checkFunc, checkInterval);
    checkFunc();

    return d.promise();
}
```

Now, if you want to test for elements one after another, you can cascade the calls like this:

```
function master() {
    waitForElement("DOM_ELEMENT1").done(function (elem1) {
        waitForElement("DOM_ELEMENT2").done(function (elem2) {
            alert("elem1 and elem2 exist!");
            // now do something with elem1 and elem2
        }).fail(function () {
            alert("elem1 exists, but elem2 was not found.");
        });
    }).fail(function () {
        alert("elem1 not found.");
    });
}
```

or you can do it in parallel and have a callback called when all of the elements exist:

```
function master() {
    $.when(
        waitForElement("DOM_ELEMENT1"),
        waitForElement("DOM_ELEMENT2")
    )
    .done(function (elem1, elem2) {
        alert("elem1 and elem2 exist!");
        // now do something with elem1 and elem2 
    })
    .fail(function () {
        alert("not all elements were found before the timeout");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `slave2` function should be passed to `slave1` function as a callback and should be called in `slave1` after it finishes (if ever?). Your current situation is quite common, since `setTimeout()` function is asynchronous, thus JS interpreter doesn't wait till the function is completed, but sets the `setTimeout()` result at the end of the Evet Loop and continues processing the master() method.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass arguments to functions, creating anonymous functions turns out to be an overkill. Consider using "bind" instead. So, if you've got

```
function slave1(str, callback){...}
function slave2(str, callback){...}
function slave3(i, callback){...}
function slave4(i, callback){...}
function slave5()
```

Instead of using

```
slave1("some argument", function(){
    slave2("another argument", function(){
        slave3(1, function(){
            slave4(2, slave5);
        });
    });
});
```

Consider using

```
slave1("some argument", 
    slave2.bind(null, "another argument",
        slave3.bind(null, 1,
            slave4.bind(null, 2, slave5)
        )
    )
);
```

Much easier, more efficient in terms of memory and CPU utilization.
Now, how to do this with setTimeout:

```
slave1("some argument",
    setTimeout.bind(null, slave2.bind(null, "another argument",
        setTimeout.bind(null, slave3.bind(null, 1,
            setTimeout.bind(null, slave4.bind(null, 2,
                setTimeout.bind(null, slave5, 0)
            ),0)
        ),0)
    ),0)
);
```

I explained the problem in more detail at 
http://morethanslightly.com/index.php/2014/09/executables-the-standard-solution-aka-mind-the-bind/